# How to install ZeroMQ 4 on Ubuntu 16.10 from source

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, zeromq

How do I install **ZeroMQ 4** on **Ubuntu 16.10** from source files?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following bash script to install **ZeroMQ 4** on **Ubuntu 16.10** machine:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Exiting on errors
set -e

# Set required version
VERSION="4.2.0"

# Asking for sudo password
sudo whoami

echo "Downloading ZeroMQ"
wget https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases/download/v${VERSION}/zeromq-${VERSION}.tar.gz

echo "Unpacking"
tar xvzf zeromq-${VERSION}.tar.gz

echo "Installing dependencies"
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y libtool pkg-config build-essential autoconf automake uuid-dev

echo "Changing directory"
cd zeromq-${VERSION}

echo "Configuring"
./configure

echo "Compiling"
make

echo "Installing"
sudo make install

echo "Installing ZeroMQ driver"
sudo ldconfig

echo "Checking installation"
ldconfig -p | grep zmq
```

Just change the version string to the required one!

[Here's the Gist for future reference.](https://gist.github.com/maxsummers/160e8f902ba4b1e27fed741cd77d206f)

Comment: There is a change in the script. When downloading the version variable should be added to one another place like - `wget https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases/download/v${VERSION}/zeromq-${VERSION}.tar.gz`